# Is it possible to slice an object?

Tags: javascript

Similar to [Array slice()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp), is it possible to slice an object (without looping though it properties)?

Simplified example:

```
var obj = {a:"one", b:"two", c:"three", d:"four"};
```

For example: Get the first 2 properties

```
var newObj = {a:"one", b:"two"};
```

Comment: `Object.key` turn it into an array ...

Comment: [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: How would you define 'first' two properties? Javascript objects' properties do not have any inherent order. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order

Comment: I vote to close this because this is already correctly answered in@JozefLegény comment **and** in the already posted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All major browsers (tested in Firefox 36, Chrome 40, Opera 27) preserve the [key order in objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) although this is [not a given in the standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order) as  Jozef Legény noted in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28807751/is-it-possible-to-slice-an-object/28810139#comment45888175_28807751):

```
> Object.keys({a: 1, b: 2})
["a", "b"]
> Object.keys({b: 2, a: 1})
["b", "a"]
```

So theoretically you can slice objects using a loop:

```
function objSlice(obj, lastExclusive) {
    var filteredKeys = Object.keys(obj).slice(0, lastExclusive);
    var newObj = {};
    filteredKeys.forEach(function(key){
        newObj[key] = obj[key];
    });
    return newObj;
}
var newObj = objSlice(obj, 2);
```

Or for example with underscore's [`omit` function](http://underscorejs.org/#omit):

```
var newObj = _.omit(obj, Object.keys(obj).slice(2));
```

Answer (score 4):

Technically objects behave like hash tables. Therefore, there is no constant entry order and the first two entries are not constantly the same. So, this is not possible, especially not without iterating over the object's entries.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `var newObj = Object.entries(obj).slice(0, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj = {a:"one", b:"two", c:"three", d:"four"};
    delete obj['d'];
    console.info(obj)
    
  /*
  sorry i forgot to put quote around d property name
   o/p
   [object Object] {
  a: "one",
  b: "two",
  c: "three"
}
  */
```